# HTTP Authorization Manager

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to JMeter.

My web app is using windows authentication. As soon as you access the page, it logs you in without the need to enter credentials (No way to log out either). I was able to use HTTP Authorization Manager + HTTP Request Sampler to access the page.

My next step is to cycle through 5 test accounts against the same HTTP Request. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like HTTP Authorization Manager supports multiple logins for the same url. Running the test, it only uses the first set of credentials.

I tried using CVS DataSet Config, but the url does not support Post or Get method for login.

Any suggestions on how I would be able to create multiple logins for a HTTP Request Sampler? If it cannot be done with the HTTP Request Sampler, any alternative samplers I should use instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out I was able to include variables within the HTTP Authorization Manager.
Combined it with the CSV Data Set Config and it works as expected!